# running powershell from batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

```
[VOID] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms ");[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname     ("System.Drawing")
 $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
 $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
 $notify.visible = $true
 $notify.showballoontip(10,"Operation Complete","All updates have been installed.",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

Is it possible to run this powershell script to display a popup balloon notification from a batch file with parameters to change the title and message?

Comment: If you want to use Powershell in a batch script, you would just use `powershell` to start, and `exit` to exit it. Everything done between entering and exiting will be treated like normal powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

PowerShell.exe ^
 [VOID] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(\"System.Windows.Forms\"); ^
 [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(\"System.Drawing\"); ^
 $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon; ^
 $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information; ^
 $notify.visible = $true; ^
 $notify.showballoontip(10,\"Operation Complete\",\"All updates have been installed.\",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

In order to change any parameter just use the usual %replacement% value in the PS lines. Remember that these lines will be evaluated as a long Batch line, and *then* executed as a PowerShell command. For the same reason, all quotes must be preceded by back-slash.

Comment: Hi Aacini, thank you very much for taking the time to respond it's working very well.

Comment: @ Aacini, when the notification has disappeared, its icon in the notification area will not disappear until the user hovers the cursor above it.

Comment: @MatthewWai: Sorry, I know nothing about how this PS code works; I just translated it to Batch code... You may do this comment to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
@ECHO OFF

PowerShell.exe

[VOID] [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms ");[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname     ("System.Drawing")
 $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
 $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
 $notify.visible = $true
 $notify.showballoontip(10,"Operation Complete","All updates have been installed.",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

Look at http://www.howtogeek.com/204088/how-to-use-a-batch-file-to-make-powershell-scripts-easier-to-run/

Comment: This not works, and this "solution" is _not_ explained at the given link...